# in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit,would it be wrong if the $\epsilon$ is a rational number rather than a real number?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, epsilon-delta

$f:E\to Y$，we write $f(x) \to q$ as $x \to p$, if

> For every positive **rational number** $\epsilon$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $d(f(x),q)<\epsilon$,for all points $x \in E$ for which $d(x,p)<\delta$.

Is that statement the same as the original one?

Comment: It is equivalent, because if you can do it for every positive rational then you can do it for every positive real, by finding a rational $\frac{1}{n}$ smaller than the given $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Yes, since rational numbers are dense

Comment: It is the same,  but I can see how you might have been marked down on a test, if the grader felt that you used the word rational without proving the equivalence.

Comment: The difference between reals and rationals is not exhibited in definition of limit but rather in existence of various limits.